# Hyperledger Fabric Go chaincode size too big

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying out the hyperledger go chaincode using the test network. I could deploy and test some basic chaincode. However, I hit a road block at some non trivial chaincode (although still very basic), as I could not deploy it onto the network using peer command line because of the error `Error: failed to endorse chaincode install: rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = grpc: received message larger than max (113972789 vs. 104857600)`.

I have tried increasing MaxRecvMsgSize and MaxSendMsgSize in the orderer.yaml and core.yaml, but if I set it to above the chaincode package size of 113972789, it does not have any effect whereas if the value is below that, then it seems to have effect.

Any suggestion on how I can solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a direct answer, but I figured out why my package was so large. It was because I didn't delete the previous package zip file, so after every build, the size got cumulatively bigger